# How to pass a parameter from Component to a Class in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, three.js, 3d

> I want to pass the parameter ColorPicker (Color1) from object-settings.component.html to poiComponentClass.ts , to assign it to the color of the cylinder ( const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xFF00FF } ); )
>
> object-settings.component.html

```
<div class="col-md-5">
      <input [style.background]="color1" [(colorPicker)]="color1" (colorPickerOpen)="onEventLog('colorPickerOpen', $event)" (colorPickerClose)="onEventLog('colorPickerClose', $event)" (cpInputChange)="onEventLog('cpInputChange', $event)" (cpSliderDragStart)="onEventLog('cpSliderDragStart', $event)" (cpSliderDragEnd)="onEventLog('cpSliderDragEnd', $event)"/>
    </div>
```

> object-settings.component.ts

```
 public onChangeColorCmyk(color: string): Cmyk
 {
 const hsva = this.cpService.stringToHsva(color);
 if (hsva) {
 const rgba = this.cpService.hsvaToRgba(hsva);
 return this.cpService.rgbaToCmyk(rgba);
 }
 return new Cmyk(0, 0, 0, 0);
 } 
 public onChangeColorHex8(color: string): string {
 const hsva = this.cpService.stringToHsva(color, true);
 if (hsva) {
 return this.cpService.outputFormat(hsva, 'rgba', null);}
 return '';}
```

> poiComponentClass.ts

```
const THREE = this.context.three;
const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 0.09, 0.09, 5, 5 );
geometry.rotateZ(-Math.PI * 0.5);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xFF00FF } );
const cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
if (!this.inputs.sprite) {
return;} 
if (!this.inputs.sprite.startsWith('/assets/')) {
textureLoader.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';}
let map;
if (this.inputs.sprite.indexOf('.gif') !== -1) {
map = new GifLoader().load(this.inputs.sprite);
 } else {
map = textureLoader.load(this.inputs.sprite);}
map.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
map.wrapS = map.wrapT = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
this.material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map, color: this.inputs.color, fog: false );
this.material.alphaTest = 0.5;
this.material.map.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
this.sprite = new THREE.Sprite( this.material );
this.sprite.add(cylinder);
this.onObjectReady(this.sprite, true);}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot missing here. We do not know the second snippet is inside a class decorated with `@Component` or not for example. There is also a lot not relevant to the question as well. If you need to learn about components communication in Angular you can start with the [Official Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) (Component Interaction).

You can use different strategies to achieve your goal, such as using a `service` (an injectable class) or using `Decorated Properties` with `Event Emitters` or even using `Facades` or `state-management libraries`. The options are manay.